# @Input() value is always undefined

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created a `user photo component` which takes an `@Input()` value, this value is the userId.  If the value is passed in then I retrieve information from `Firebase` linking to this userId, if it doesn't then I do something else.

My user-photo component

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'user-photos',
    templateUrl: './user-photos.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./user-photos.component.css']
})

export class UserPhotoComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() userId: string;

    constructor() { 

        console.log('userId is:',this.userId);

    }


    ngOnInit() {


    }

    ngOnDestroy() {

    }
}
```

As you can see I have declared the userId as `@Input()`, now on my `edit-profile component` I have the following:

```
<user-photos [userId]="TestingInput"></user-photos>
```

Now the User Photo component gets rendered as I see the `h1` tag appearing, however the userId is always undefined ?

No errors are appearing in the developer console, so I'm not entirely sure what I've done wrong.

Answer (score 190, accepted):

It will be initialized in `ngOnInit`, not the constructor. (*Please also review the [Angular Life Cycle Hooks documentation](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).*)

```
ngOnInit() {
  console.log('userId is:',this.userId);
}
```

Also if you want to pass a literal like a string and use brackets `[]` you have to pass it as a string by enclosing the value with single ticks.

```
<user-photos [userId]="'TestingInput'"></user-photos>
```

The reason for that is the containing expression is evaluated in the context of the containing component so without it it will try to retrieve and pass a property/field named `TestingInput` which will be undefined (*unless you also happen have a field by that name*).

Comment: Can confirm it works, perfect thanks for your help and the additional information.  Can't accept answer at the moment have to wait three minutes.  Will do it asap.

Answer (score 19):

In my case i had to use *ngIf = "isLoaded" on the parent's template first.

**On Parent Component**

```
    <div *ngIf = "isLoaded">
       <app-child-component [dataToChild]="dataFromParent"> </app-child-component>
    </div>
```

**On Child Component**

```
      @Input() dataToChild: any;
        constructor() { }
        ngOnInit(): void {
             console.log(this.dataToChild);
         }
```

Comment: I was able to use this code.
`<div *ngIf = "dataFromParent">
       <app-child-component [dataToChild]="dataFromParent"> </app-child-component>
    </div>`

Comment: @user2814648 Just wanted to say OVER a year later - and after literally 4 hours of squeezing stackoverflow  YOUR answer was the one that worked.  Thank you so much!

Comment: *ngIf indeed! Thanks bruh!

Comment: This guy saved me after 2 hours of non-stop craziness, legend!  Thank you!

Answer (score 17):

If your input comes delayed (e.g. a slow webservice), the value will at first be undefined until the response arrives from the webservice.

In order to debug this, you could use ngOnChanges() hook, which will fire every time, an input value changes:

```
ngOnChanges() {
  console.log('data', this.data);
}
```

which will output something like:

`data undefined` <- OnInit, value did not arrive yet

`data here it is!` <- value arrives delayed

Comment: Is there any other way other than using the onChanges hook.

Comment: Yes, you could change the type of the input data: instead of @Input() inputData: MyDataType, you can use @Input() inputData: Subject<MyDataType>. Then you can create a class Subscription variable. in th ngOnInit() life cycle hook, you subscribe to the subject as you normally would with an Observable and in the ngOnDestroy, you unsubscribe from the class Subscription variable. In the parent-component you must then use the subjVar.next(value) to stream the value to the subject wrapper so it can be caught in the child component.

Answer (score 10):

In my case, I was passing in `undefined` as an *input* and I was assuming that Angular will treat the case of undefined the same as the default scenario. This assumption was wrong even if it is not clearly outlined in [Angular's Component Interaction documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction). Here is the use case scenario:

parent.component.html:

```
...
[mVal]="undefined"
...
```

child.component.ts:

```
...
@input('mVal')
mVal: boolean = true
...
```

The value of `mVal` will be `undefined` and not `true` as you might have expected.

Angular will make the value true (default case) only if it is *not defined* on the parent component; otherwise, **it will pass-in the value as it is** (even if it is `undefined`).

You can solve this by checking if the value is undefined on [`OnInit`](https://angular.io/api/core/OnInit) or even in the component's constructor.

Answer (score 5):

I spent a lot of time for this stupidest @Input mistake. It should be:

```html
<user-photos
  [userId]="TestingInput">
</user-photos>
```

and not

```html
<user-photos>
  [userId]="TestingInput"
</user-photos>
```

Maybe it will help if someone has made a syntax mistake like I did

Answer (score 4):

In case TestingInput is a **variable** and **not value** is better add `*ngIf="TestingInput"`

```
<user-photos [userId]="TestingInput" *ngIf="TestingInput "></user-photos>
```

if we are calling some api, the delay of the response may cause to pass an empty value

Answer (score 2):

Use single ticks if you want to use a hardcoded string as parameter

```
<app-mycomponent [inputProperty]="'test'"></app-mycomponent>
```

Answer (score 1):

any of these answers is not working for me, after some research I have found belove solution,

in HTML.

```
<app-opportunityTable [tableNAme]="'OPPORTUNITY'"></app-opportunityTable>
```

in child component

```
@Component( {
    selector: 'app-opportunityTable',
    templateUrl: './opportunityTable.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./opportunityTable.component.css'],
    inputs: ['tableNAme']
} )

export class opportunityTable implements OnInit {
         ngOnInit() {
        console.log( "this is it" + this.tableNAme )
         }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering your question

> @Input() value is always undefined

The reason you're getting undefined in ngOnInit is because at the point where the component is initialised you haven't actually passed in userId.

```
<user-photos [userId]="TestingInput"></user-photos>
```

In order to get @Input value in the OnInit() function you can do something like :

> My user-photo component

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'user-photos',
    templateUrl: './user-photos.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./user-photos.component.css']
})

export class UserPhotoComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() userId: string;

    constructor() {  }

    ngOnInit() {
     setTimeout(() => {
         console.log('userId is:',this.userId);  // You will get the @Input value
     });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {

    }
}
```

Comment: Did it work for you? I get the same thing, undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It can also be undefined if you have multiple inputs, in my version of Angular this is the case:

```js
export class Foo {
    @Input() bar: string; // fine
    @Input() baz: string; // does not exist (console.log(this) does not show it)
}
```

Does not matter whether you pass it in as well. It seems that earlier versions of Angular do not allow this. If you need multiple inputs pass in one object with multiple fields.

Comment: This isn't accurate. You can add any number of inputs to a component, so something else is going on with your code if baz doesn't exist.

Comment: As i stated in the answer, in my *specific version* of angular this did not work. I know it works on newer versions. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42454816/4021308. I edited my answer to make it more clear