# @Input not working in ionic 3 custom component from a lazy loaded page

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic3

I want to pass a titleKey parameter to a custom module `navbar` isolated in a `components.module.ts` from a lazy loaded page.

## components.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [NavbarComponent],
    imports: [
      IonicModule,
      CommonModule],
    exports: [NavbarComponent],
    schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
```

## navbar.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'navbar',
  templateUrl: 'navbar.html',
  inputs: ['titleKey']
})
export class NavbarComponent {
  @Input() titleKey:string;


  constructor(private navCtrl:NavController) {
  }
}
```

When I use this `navbar` inside a lazy loaded page, the input doesn't work

## home.html

```
<ion-header>
    <navbar titleKey="my custom title"></navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
    .....
</ion-content>
```

If I print the result of the `@Input() titleKey:string` inside the `navbar.component.ts`, it is undefined.

I already tried to call this navbar in other forms but it doesn't seems to work.

```
<ion-header>
    <navbar [titleKey]="my custom title"></navbar>
</ion-header>

and

<ion-header>
    <navbar [titleKey]="'my custom title'"></navbar>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: if you declare your input inside `inputs` property of component's decorator, I think you shouldn't decorate them inside  your class member declaration. So, try removing the `inputs` property inside the component decorator, or remove the decorator `@Input()` before your declaration.

Comment: not sure whether it was solved or not, but try with `@Input() public titleKey: string;`. Then, in `ngOnInit`, do: `console.log(this.titleKey);`. Also, why are you using `inputs`?

Comment: keep console.log(this.titleKey) in ngInit and check. Not in constructor

Comment: @Florian i'm going to try it

Comment: @Geetesh why I cannot use it in the constructor ?

Comment: @JulianGarzon : decorator should be use to setup angular DI, but not much else. In this case, you can do both, but note that it is a bad practise to have "work" in your constructor.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123170/input-value-is-always-undefined/42123223

Comment: I think @Florian is right either of  `inputs` or `@input` should be used.

Comment: yes `ngOnInit` solves the problem, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with lazy loaded web components. It seems like the @Input is set after the component is initialized and does not trigger an update.

To fix this, for lazy loaded components i'm using getters and setters for inputs and trigger initialization logic. You may also want to check if you're in the same zone, if not you may have to inject NgZone and use zone.run() to trigger an update

```
private _titleKey: string;

@Input()
set titleKey(value: string) { this._titleKey = value; this.ngOnInit(); }
get titleKey(): string { return this._titleKey; }
```

Comment: Have you tried triggering a change detection ? `@input()` decorated variables should be updated each time change detection runs