# Why I can not get data from @input?

Tags: angular

Inside constructor of component A I use this code:

```
public visitors: any[] = [];
 this.eventsService.view(this.activatedRoute.snapshot.params['id']).subscribe(response => {
      this.event = response.data.event;
      this.visitors = response.data.event.visitors;
});
```

Component A template is:

```
<app-visitor-component [visitors]="visitors"></app-visitor-component>
```

Why I variable `visitors` in `app-visitor-component` component is empty, despite on data exists:

```
@Input() visitors: IVisitor[];
 constructor() {
     console.log(this.visitors); // returns []
 }
```

Comment: Just use `*ngIf` to only render `app-visitor-component` only once `visitors` has data/length if you are needing it to be populated at the time of `ngOnInit()`. It is always coming out to `[]` in `contructor`/`ngOnInit()` because the asynchronous call to populate `visitors` only completes **after** `contructor`/`ngOnInit()` of the child component is executed. Otherwise there are other lifecycle methods like OnChanges, where you can capture updates to that @Input. Try even at minimum to visualize this put some console.log() statements inside the subscribe as well as in `contructor`/`ngOnInit`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `ComponentA` template the `visitor` the easiest thing to do if you expect a value for the binding of `visitor` in child components is to add a `*ngIf` check.

```
<app-visitor-component *ngIf="visitors.length" [visitors]="visitors"></app-visitor-component>
```

That does a truthy check on the value of `visitors.length` which will evaluate to `false` until the service call returns a value.

Also I would recommend you move the service call to `eventsService.view` to the `ngOnInit` of `ComponentA` and out of the constructor. This also makes `ComponentA` easier to test.

---

Then in the child component for `app-visitor`

From a previous answer [@Input() value is always undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123170/input-value-is-always-undefined)

> It will be initialized in `ngOnInit`, not the constructor. (*Please also review the [Angular Life Cycle Hooks documentation](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks).*)

Your code using `OnInit`

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-visitor-component',
    templateUrl: ''
})
export class ComponentAppVisitor implements OnInit {

    @Input() visitors: IVisitor[];
    constructor() {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.visitors);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, I tried `  ngOnInit() {
        console.log(this.visitors);
    }
` it is empty []

Comment: @OPV - but it isn't. You are writing your code in the `constructor`. The data will always be undefined because the binding has not yet occurred.

Comment: @OPV - the other reason that nothing is being passed is that there is no value until your service call returns with a value. See the updated template code, you can add an `*ngIf` check to ensure that the `app-visitor` component does not get created until after the parent component has a value.

Comment: `*ngIf="visitors"` is not enough, you would need to at minimum check length as they are defaulting to empty array `[]`.

Comment: @AlexanderStaroselsky - you are right, I overlooked the initial value assignment.

Comment: I tried: `<app-visitor-component *ngIf="visitors" [visitors]="visitors"></app-visitor-component>` does not work

Comment: @OPV - see the update from 2 min. ago. That should be `*ngIf="visitors.length"`

Comment: Upper this line I have data `{{visitors | json }}`, but inside component it is always []

Comment: @Igor when data biding will be changing the code is not running since it's in ngOnInit not in ngOnchanges

Answer (score 1):

Angular **doesn't make the `@Input` data available** as soon as the component is created. I.e. it's not available during the `constructor()`.

If you want to key off when the `@Input` is actually sent (and re-sent) use NgOnChanges:

```
import { Component, Input, OnChanges } from @angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'app-foo',
})
export class FooComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input() visitors: IVisitor[];
    ngOnChanges() {
        if (this.visitors) {
            console.log(this.visitors)
            // do something with this.visitors
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively you can use getter/setters to trigger something when it's sent by Angular:

```
    private _visitors: IVisitor[];
    @Input() public set visitors(val: IVisitor[]) {
        this._visitors = val;
    }
    // Also, guarantee to always return an array
    public get visitors(): IVisitor[] {
        if (this._visitors) {
            return this._visitors;
        }
        return [];
    }
```