# Unable to access Input Property in NgOnInit -Angular 6

Tags: angular

My Parent page looks like this.

html:

```
<counter  [conversationId]="conversationId"></counter>
```

component:

```
public conversationId: string;

public showModal() {   
 this.conversationId = '1234'
 this.modalService.showComponent(CounterPage, { class: 'modal-lg' }); 
}
```

My Child page looks like this.

```
 @Input() conversationId: any;
 public ngOnInit  (): void {
    alert(this.conversationId); //shows undefinded.
  }
```

Looks like this is common issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42123170/input-value-is-always-undefined). None of the solutions worked for me.

Comment: What is `conversationId` when it is being passed in? If you are passing in `undefined` then it would make sense that it remains `undefined`.

Comment: I am not passing undefined. My code clearly shows assigning '1234' to conversationId before calling show component

Answer (score 0):

The params receive values before the method ngAfterContentInit().

See the lifecycle of angular in this image: https://v2.angular.io/resources/images/devguide/lifecycle-hooks/hooks-in-sequence.png

try:

```
@Input() conversationId: any;
 public ngAfterContentInit  (): void {
    alert(this.conversationId); //shows undefinded.
  }
```

Comment: so, what is the best way to access conversationId ?

Comment: The best ways I know of are using ngAfterContentInit or the constructor, however I prefer to use ngAfterContentInit

Comment: value is not showing in nfAfterContentInit, your code comments shows undefined